# Convert string to array of strings using python

Tags: python, arrays, string

I have a string like `"['apple' 'bat' 'cat']"`.
The string need to convert into array like:`['apple','bat','cat']`

Comment: `['apple' 'bat' 'cat']` isn't a valid object in python, so you can't have that as starting point. You need to be precise in your questions. What's the starting object? The string `"['apple' 'bat' 'cat']"` or the array `['apple', 'bat', 'cat']`?

Comment: So, this is a string "['apple' 'bat' 'cat']"  and I want to convert this to array ['apple', 'bat', 'cat']

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. I edited the question again

Comment: Decode the json

Comment: So generally you want to convert a string of a literal to the equivalent value of the literal?

Comment: Can elements contain spaces and/or quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the first `[` and last `]` elements of your string

then split the remaining string into their elements

Iterate then each element and remove the opening and closing quote (first and last element)

Merge everything in a list comprehension

```
my_string = "['apple' 'bat' 'cat']"
result = [i[1:-1] for i in my_string[1:-1].split(' ')]
print(result)

['apple', 'bat', 'cat']
```

Comment: Note that this fails if an element contains a space.